# Elastic search query returns empty result

Tags: elasticsearch

The following query is returning an empty result even though there are results matching the query.

```
GET abc*/_search
        {
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {"range": {
                  "timestamp": {
                    "gte": "2018-01-01T00:00:00.000",
                    "lte": "2018-01-02T12:00:00.465"
                  }
                }}
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

When I replace must with must_not I am getting results.The following is my index data

```
{
      "took": 0,
      "timed_out": false,
      "_shards": {
        "total": 6,
        "successful": 6,
        "skipped": 0,
        "failed": 0
      },
      "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 1,
        "hits": [
          {
            "_index": "abc",
            "_type": "log",
            "_id": "abc3423498239048290",
            "_score": 1,
            "_source": {
              "0": {
                "test": 289,
                "testnested": {
                  "testnested1": 0,
                  "testnested2": 0.615,
                     },
                "test1": 46.17,
                "test2": 59.4,            
                "ts": "2018-01-01T00:08:20.396UTC"
              },
              "1":{
                ----------
                ----------
               },
              ........
              "10":{
                ------------------
              },
              "timestamp": "2018-01-01T00:08:20.396UTC",
             }
    -----------
       }
```

Is there anything I am doing wrong?.timestamp field is of type "date_hour_minute_second_millis".I am using Elasticsearch version 5+. I have used this same query in another index and it is working there.

Comment: I guess it's quite probable that server timezone is other than UTC, so your range timestamp `2018-01-01T00:00:00.000` may be treated as something like `2018-01-01T03:00:00.000UTC`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried it, but getting an exception

Comment: failed to parse date field [2018-01-01T00:00:00.000UTC] with format [date_hour_minute_second_millis]

Comment: @Etki Instead of modifying the search parameter I modified the timestamp in the index. Since it was not in the correct format. The format I was expecting is "date_hour_minute_second_millis" and I used the wrong format. After the update, my query works fine. Thanks for your hint.